# How to have a field in a struct referencing to a value in the main function in rust?

Tags: rust, sfml

I need to make a struct called `Ant` which stores an instance of [Sprite](https://docs.rs/sfml/0.16.0/sfml/graphics/struct.Sprite.html), to create a Sprite i need a reference to [Texture](https://docs.rs/sfml/0.16.0/sfml/graphics/struct.Texture.html), i will create about hundred instances of Ant, but all of the Sprites inside each instance needs the same texture.
Here's my code right now-

```rust
struct Ant<'a> {
    sprite: Sprite<'a>,
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    direction: f32,
    speed: f32,
}

impl Ant<'_> {
    fn new(texture: &SfBox<Texture>, x: f32, y: f32, direction: f32) -> Self {
        let sprite = Sprite::with_texture(texture);
        Ant {
            sprite,
            x,
            y,
            direction,
            speed: 4.
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let texture = Texture::from_file("ant.png").unwrap();
    let ant = Ant::new(&texture, 0., 0., 60.);
}
```

Now the error I'm getting is-

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:18:43
   |
18 |         let sprite = Sprite::with_texture(texture);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 17:21...
  --> src/main.rs:17:21
   |
17 |     fn new(texture: &SfBox<Texture>, x: f32, y: f32, direction: f32) -> Self {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:18:43
   |
18 |         let sprite = Sprite::with_texture(texture);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined on the impl at 16:10...
  --> src/main.rs:16:10
   |
16 | impl Ant<'_> {
   |          ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 | /         Ant {
20 | |             sprite,
21 | |             x,
22 | |             y,
23 | |             direction,
24 | |             speed: 4.
25 | |         }
   | |_________^
   = note: expected `Ant<'_>`
              found `Ant<'_>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Does anyone know how can i go about to do this?

Comment: Don't keep multiple references to the same non copy value, but a key (for example an index) which will be used on display to access the texture. To make this cleaner, remember that you can define type aliases for indexes.

Comment: Did you try taking `texture` by `&'a Texture` (instead of a reference to a box), and making the whole `impl Ant<'a>`?

Answer (score 1):

Every `&` reference has a lifetime; if you don't write one, then the compiler picks it for you (an *elided lifetime*). When you write

```rust
impl Ant<'_> {
    fn new(texture: &SfBox<Texture>, x: f32, y: f32, direction: f32) -> Self {
```

the elided lifetime for `texture` only lasts at least as long as the function call to `new`. You need to link it to the lifetime of the `Ant` struct, instead, since you're trying to store the `Sprite` that depends on the texture reference in the `Ant` struct:

```rust
impl<'a> Ant<'a> {
    fn new(texture: &'a SfBox<Texture>, x: f32, y: f32, direction: f32) -> Self {
```

This should solve the lifetime problem you present. I'm not familiar with `sfml` and so there might be other problems with the code.